# Is there an easy way to check whether an Android device supports ETC2 and ASTC?

Tags: android, opengl-es, astc

Is there an easy way to check whether an Android device supports ETC2 and ASTC? 
By the way, I don't want to create an OpenGL context to get the extensions, that’s because I need to know the support features to request the right texture resources from the remote server.

Comment: Why don't you want to create a context? It's the correct way to do this ...

Comment: If you can live with the false-negatives you could check for the Android Extension Pack (guarantees ASTC) `boolean deviceSupportsAEP = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_OPENGLES_EXTENSION_PACK);`